# vertica Received fatal signal SIGSEGV

Tags: vertica

One of my vertica cluster node down, and in log file a found :

```
2016-03-19 20:01:55.263 Init Session:0x7f3420013970-b00000000a70ab [EE]      <INFO> SortManager found maxMerges 7 too small(38 MB Assigned).
    2016-03-19 20:01:55.263 Init Session:0x7f3420013970-b00000000a70ab [EE] <INFO> After disabling optimization, maxMerges becomes 7.
    2016-03-19 20:01:55.266 nameless:0x7f325accb730 [Main] <INFO> Handling signal: 11
    2016-03-19 20:01:55.291 Init Session:0x7f3420013970-b00000000a70ab [EE] <INFO> SortManager found maxMerges 7 too small(38 MB Assigned).
    2016-03-19 20:01:55.291 Init Session:0x7f3420013970-b00000000a70ab [EE] <INFO> After disabling optimization, maxMerges becomes 7.
    2016-03-19 20:01:55.292 Init Session:0x7f3420013970-b00000000a70ab [EE] <INFO> SortManager found maxMerges 7 too small(38 MB Assigned).
    2016-03-19 20:01:55.292 Init Session:0x7f3420013970-b00000000a70ab [EE] <INFO> After disabling optimization, maxMerges becomes 7.
    2016-03-19 20:01:55.292 Init Session:0x7f3420013970-b00000000a70ab [EE] <INFO> SortManager found maxMerges 7 too small(38 MB Assigned).
    2016-03-19 20:01:55.292 Init Session:0x7f3420013970-b00000000a70ab [EE] <INFO> After disabling optimization, maxMerges becomes 7.
    2016-03-19 20:01:55.293 Init Session:0x7f3420013970-b00000000a70ab [EE] <INFO> SortManager found maxMerges 7 too small(38 MB Assigned).
    2016-03-19 20:01:55.293 Init Session:0x7f3420013970-b00000000a70ab [EE] <INFO> After disabling optimization, maxMerges becomes 7.
    2016-03-19 20:01:55.294 Init Session:0x7f3420013970-b00000000a70ab [EE] <INFO> SortManager found maxMerges 7 too small(38 MB Assigned).
    2016-03-19 20:01:55.294 Init Session:0x7f3420013970-b00000000a70ab [EE] <INFO> After disabling optimization, maxMerges becomes 7.
    2016-03-19 20:01:55.294 Init Session:0x7f3420013970-b00000000a70ab [EE] <INFO> SortManager found maxMerges 7 too small(38 MB Assigned).
    2016-03-19 20:01:55.294 Init Session:0x7f3420013970-b00000000a70ab [EE] <INFO> After disabling optimization, maxMerges becomes 7.
    2016-03-19 20:01:55.295 Init Session:0x7f3420013970-b00000000a70ab [EE] <INFO> SortManager found maxMerges 7 too small(38 MB Assigned).
    2016-03-19 20:01:55.295 Init Session:0x7f3420013970-b00000000a70ab [EE] <INFO> After disabling optimization, maxMerges becomes 7.
    2016-03-19 20:01:55.296 Init Session:0x7f3420013970-b00000000a70ab [EE] <INFO> SortManager found maxMerges 7 too small(38 MB Assigned).
    2016-03-19 20:01:55.296 Init Session:0x7f3420013970-b00000000a70ab [EE] <INFO> After disabling optimization, maxMerges becomes 7.
    2016-03-19 20:01:55.297 Init Session:0x7f3420013970-b00000000a70ab [EE] <INFO> SortManager found maxMerges 7 too small(38 MB Assigned).
    2016-03-19 20:01:55.297 Init Session:0x7f3420013970-b00000000a70ab [EE] <INFO> After disabling optimization, maxMerges becomes 7.
    2016-03-19 20:01:55.297 Init Session:0x7f3420013970-b00000000a70ab [EE] <INFO> SortManager found maxMerges 7 too small(38 MB Assigned).
    2016-03-19 20:01:55.297 Init Session:0x7f3420013970-b00000000a70ab [EE] <INFO> After disabling optimization, maxMerges becomes 7.
    2016-03-19 20:01:55.298 Init Session:0x7f3420013970-b00000000a70ab [EE] <INFO> SortManager found maxMerges 7 too small(38 MB Assigned).
    2016-03-19 20:01:55.298 Init Session:0x7f3420013970-b00000000a70ab [EE] <INFO> After disabling optimization, maxMerges becomes 7.
    2016-03-19 20:01:55.305 EEThread:0x7f307fab12c0-c0000000099401 [EE] <INFO> Running ROS from sort buffer. Merge chunks = 1, merges per batch = 36
    2016-03-19 20:01:55.305 EEThread:0x7f3379799f10-c0000000099401 [EE] <INFO> Running ROS from sort buffer. Merge chunks = 1, merges per batch = 36
    2016-03-19 20:01:55.305 EEThread:0x7f2fb3edbea0-c0000000099401 [EE] <INFO> Running ROS from sort buffer. Merge chunks = 1, merges per batch = 36
    2016-03-19 20:01:55.306 EEThread:0x7f307fab12c0-c0000000099401 [EE] <INFO> Finished writing one ROS at 0.00 sec. Write cost 0.00 sec, including compress pipe wait 0.00 sec
    2016-03-19 20:01:55.306 EEThread:0x7f3379799f10-c0000000099401 [EE] <INFO> Finished writing one ROS at 0.00 sec. Write cost 0.00 sec, including compress pipe wait 0.00 sec
    2016-03-19 20:01:55.307 EEThread:0x7f2fb3edbea0-c0000000099401 [EE] <INFO> Finished writing one ROS at 0.00 sec. Write cost 0.00 sec, including compress pipe wait 0.00 sec
    2016-03-19 20:01:55.308 EEThread:0x7f307fab12c0-c0000000099401 [EE] <INFO> Finished writing ROSes from sort buffer.
    2016-03-19 20:01:55.309 EEThread:0x7f3379799f10-c0000000099401 [EE] <INFO> Finished writing ROSes from sort buffer.
    2016-03-19 20:01:55.309 EEThread:0x7f2fb3edbea0-c0000000099401 [EE] <INFO> Finished writing ROSes from sort buffer.
    2016-03-19 20:01:56.780 nameless:0x7f325accb730 [Main] <PANIC> Received fatal signal SIGSEGV.
    2016-03-19 20:01:56.780 nameless:0x7f325accb730 [Main] <PANIC> Info: si_code: 128, si_pid: 0, si_uid: 0, si_addr: (nil)
```

ErrorReport.txt

```
BEGIN BACKTRACE
Vertica Backtrace at Sat Mar 19 20:01:55 2016
-------------------------
Vertica Analytic Database v7.2.1-0 $BrandId$
vertica(v7.2.1-0) built by jeeves@build-centos6 from releases/VER_7_2_RELEASE_BUILD_1_0_20151116@177918 on 'Mon Nov 16 16:59:07 2015' $BuildId$
00400000-0485f000 r-xp 00000000 fc:03 52166764                           /opt/vertica/bin/vertica
0485f000-07020000 rw-p 0445f000 fc:03 52166764                           /opt/vertica/bin/vertica
07020000-07139000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
08931000-08e42000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f34c7538000-7f34c7801000 r--p 00000000 fc:03 8650892                    /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
7f34c7801000-7f34c8746000 r--s 00000000 fc:03 52168242                   /opt/vertica/share/icu/icudt42l.dat
7f34c8746000-7f34c8751000 r-xp 00000000 fc:03 28573925                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.19.so
7f34c8751000-7f34c8950000 ---p 0000b000 fc:03 28573925                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.19.so
7f34c8950000-7f34c8951000 r--p 0000a000 fc:03 28573925                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.19.so
7f34c8951000-7f34c8952000 rw-p 0000b000 fc:03 28573925                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.19.so
7f34c8952000-7f34c895d000 r-xp 00000000 fc:03 28573915                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.19.so
7f34c895d000-7f34c8b5c000 ---p 0000b000 fc:03 28573915                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.19.so
7f34c8b5c000-7f34c8b5d000 r--p 0000a000 fc:03 28573915                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.19.so
7f34c8b5d000-7f34c8b5e000 rw-p 0000b000 fc:03 28573915                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.19.so
7f34c8b5e000-7f34c8b75000 r-xp 00000000 fc:03 28573909                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.19.so
7f34c8b75000-7f34c8d74000 ---p 00017000 fc:03 28573909                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.19.so
7f34c8d74000-7f34c8d75000 r--p 00016000 fc:03 28573909                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.19.so
7f34c8d75000-7f34c8d76000 rw-p 00017000 fc:03 28573909                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.19.so
7f34c8d76000-7f34c8d78000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f34c8d78000-7f34c8d81000 r-xp 00000000 fc:03 28573908                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.19.so
7f34c8d81000-7f34c8f80000 ---p 00009000 fc:03 28573908                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.19.so
7f34c8f80000-7f34c8f81000 r--p 00008000 fc:03 28573908                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.19.so
7f34c8f81000-7f34c8f82000 rw-p 00009000 fc:03 28573908                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.19.so
7f34c8f82000-7f34c9384000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f34c9384000-7f34d9524000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f34d9524000-7f34d9725000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f34d9725000-7f34d974a000 r-xp 00000000 fc:03 28573816                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5.9
7f34d974a000-7f34d9949000 ---p 00025000 fc:03 28573816                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5.9
7f34d9949000-7f34d994d000 r--p 00024000 fc:03 28573816                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5.9
7f34d994d000-7f34d994e000 rw-p 00028000 fc:03 28573816                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5.9
7f34d994e000-7f34d9964000 r-xp 00000000 fc:03 28573714                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f34d9964000-7f34d9b63000 ---p 00016000 fc:03 28573714                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f34d9b63000-7f34d9b64000 rw-p 00015000 fc:03 28573714                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f34d9b64000-7f34d9b7d000 r-xp 00000000 fc:03 28573910                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.19.so
7f34d9b7d000-7f34d9d7c000 ---p 00019000 fc:03 28573910                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.19.so
7f34d9d7c000-7f34d9d7d000 r--p 00018000 fc:03 28573910                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.19.so
7f34d9d7d000-7f34d9d7e000 rw-p 00019000 fc:03 28573910                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.19.so
7f34d9d7e000-7f34d9d82000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f34d9d82000-7f34d9d85000 r-xp 00000000 fc:03 28573904                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.19.so
7f34d9d85000-7f34d9f84000 ---p 00003000 fc:03 28573904                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.19.so
7f34d9f84000-7f34d9f85000 r--p 00002000 fc:03 28573904                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.19.so
7f34d9f85000-7f34d9f86000 rw-p 00003000 fc:03 28573904                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.19.so
7f34d9f86000-7f34da141000 r-xp 00000000 fc:03 28573922                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
7f34da141000-7f34da340000 ---p 001bb000 fc:03 28573922                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
7f34da340000-7f34da344000 r--p 001ba000 fc:03 28573922                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
7f34da344000-7f34da346000 rw-p 001be000 fc:03 28573922                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
7f34da346000-7f34da34b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f34da34b000-7f34da352000 r-xp 00000000 fc:03 28573920                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.19.so
7f34da352000-7f34da551000 ---p 00007000 fc:03 28573920                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.19.so
7f34da551000-7f34da552000 r--p 00006000 fc:03 28573920                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.19.so
7f34da552000-7f34da553000 rw-p 00007000 fc:03 28573920                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.19.so
7f34da553000-7f34da639000 r-xp 00000000 fc:03 8652997                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19
7f34da639000-7f34da838000 ---p 000e6000 fc:03 8652997                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19
7f34da838000-7f34da840000 r--p 000e5000 fc:03 8652997                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19
7f34da840000-7f34da842000 rw-p 000ed000 fc:03 8652997                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19
7f34da842000-7f34da857000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f34da857000-7f34da95c000 r-xp 00000000 fc:03 28573902                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.19.so
7f34da95c000-7f34dab5b000 ---p 00105000 fc:03 28573902                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.19.so
7f34dab5b000-7f34dab5c000 r--p 00104000 fc:03 28573902                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.19.so
7f34dab5c000-7f34dab5d000 rw-p 00105000 fc:03 28573902                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.19.so
7f34dab5d000-7f34dab7f000 r-xp 00000000 fc:03 28573771                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so.5.9
7f34dab7f000-7f34dad7e000 ---p 00022000 fc:03 28573771                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so.5.9
7f34dad7e000-7f34dad7f000 r--p 00021000 fc:03 28573771                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so.5.9
7f34dad7f000-7f34dad80000 rw-p 00022000 fc:03 28573771                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so.5.9
7f34dad80000-7f34dada3000 r-xp 00000000 fc:03 28573912                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
7f34dadda000-7f34dade2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f34dade2000-7f34daf87000 r-xp 00000000 fc:03 52175026                   /opt/vertica/lib/libAutopassCrypto64.so
7f34daf87000-7f34daf9b000 rw-p 001a4000 fc:03 52175026                   /opt/vertica/lib/libAutopassCrypto64.so
7f34dafa0000-7f34dafa2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f34dafa2000-7f34dafa3000 r--p 00022000 fc:03 28573912                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
7f34dafa3000-7f34dafa4000 rw-p 00023000 fc:03 28573912                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
7f34dafa4000-7f34dafa5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffe326d1000-7ffe326f2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffe327fe000-7ffe32800000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]

Backtrace Generated by Error
Signal: [0x000000000000000b] PID: [0x0000000000007232] PC: [0x0000000000ad5ec7] FP: [0x00007f2f638c0a40] SIGSEGV: SI_ADDR : [0x0000000000000000]
/opt/vertica/bin/vertica[0x301ecd7]
/opt/vertica/bin/vertica[0x306b464]
/opt/vertica/bin/vertica[0x306c6c9]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x36d40)[0x7f34d9fbcd40]
/opt/vertica/bin/vertica[0xad5ec7]
/opt/vertica/bin/vertica[0xb09e64]
/opt/vertica/bin/vertica[0xa9c787]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x498b0)[0x7f34d9fcf8b0]
END BACKTRACE
NO THREAD CONTEXT
```

Maybe someone now the reason of this crash ?

Comment: Was there anything after the last message? Can you post the output of `ErrorReport.txt` ? Were there any changes made to the cluster?

Comment: Were you running unfenced UDxs? Anyhow... I'd suggest you to contact Vertica's support...

Answer (score 0):

Basically, this can mean a lot of things, from my experience, and assuming you already tried to debug other reasons, this means that the "sideways optimization" mechanism (which is one of Vertica's best features in terms of run-time to get you the results asap) is encountering an issue.
Previously I've encountered this scenario when a certain query was causing it, when an edge case of multiple processes (Tuple Mover during heavy querying) and just sometimes randomly to be honest.
Cases I've opened resulted in a "this is related to a Vertica bug, please upgrade to the latest version" kind of an answer, however i was sure this was resolved by 7.2.x, which i see you're in.
There is a way around this, but that will involve disabling the "sideways" feature, either partially or completely.
If the problem persists and you can't get a Vertica response (or are not paying for support) this is the config param you need to change: "EnableEMMJMultiblockSIPS"
Keep in mind, this will (theoretically) degrade your performance.
Also, the "change_under_support_guidance" flag is on for this, so theoretically you should "consult your doctor" before changing it...
Hope this helps.
Ari